# Can I use only redis and node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

I've already looked on the internet and it only gave me doubts what architecture to use.

I am thinking of using:

BackEnd:
Nodejs, Mongo, Redis.

FrontEnd:
You travel

Because it is a chat application with the possibility of scaling horizontally.

The big question is do I have to use Mongo?

If not, use Redis, it is safe to treat with user.

Or leave the Mongo for user, and Redis for msg.

I thank anyone who has worked with something like this or knows the subject more than I ... Grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can just use mongodb or redis or mysql and so on.

On the whole:

- MongoDB: a document database
- MySQL: a relational database
- Redis: a in-memory data structure store. Of course, you can use redis as a database, but more people use it as cache to speed up request processing

So, I think you can use mongo or mysql as base storage. If your data too big, you can you add redis when your want to speed up request